# AngularJs http post cant reach the local folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

HTML

```
 <input type="file" file-model="image" multiple/>
<button type="submit" class="btn-sm" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
```

In the html, i have an input like this.

JS

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
           var model = $parse(attributes.fileModel);
           var modelSetter = model.assign;
           element.bind('change', function(){
               scope.$apply(function(){
                   modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
               });
           });
       }
   };}]);
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    });
};}]);
app.controller('storeController',['$http','$scope','fileUpload',function($http,$scope,fileUpload) {

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.image;


        console.log('file is ' );
        console.dir(file);

        var uploadUrl = "././img/";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };
```

I'm trying to upload image with this code to server/local folder. But it's responding with HTTP 404 error on console.

It's correctly logging the file to the console but when i try to post it to folder,not working.

There is a folder at root called by img. Url is correct,there isn't any syntax error about writing the url but it is responding with

```
POST http://localhost:63342/Project/img/ 404 (Not Found)
```

error at the console.

What can i do to make it work ?

Comment: You need to create an endpoint on your server that handle the file upload request that copy it to the destination folder, it doesn't copy the file automatically (Thanks god)

Comment: How can i do it ? I'm not professional.I was supposing file will be saved to folder with http.post code.

Comment: No, Think about it - How long will it take for your server to be uploaded with tons of viruses if this would possible? You must implement it using any server side language (Python/PHP/Node.js....)

Comment: The code is in the admin panel. So why i didn't think about viruses or some troubles like that.I will try to upload data by before posting it to php or something what can work at serverside.Is it true ? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: That is correct. and you should search for handling file upload using php on Google for [tutorials](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=handle%20file%20upload%20php)

Comment: Thank you so much again. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access your folder structure from JavaScript and you cannot access it with a URL either, for security reasons of course.

Otherwise anyone could write a little bit of JavaScript and do whatever they want with your files.

Plus the URL is a virtual path not a physical one. You can save a file to a physical location, but you can't do the same with a virtual one.

You didn't say how your app is structured, assuming you have a back end like MVC for example, you could do this on that side. Just create an endpoint you hit from JavaScript and let the back end code deal with the uploaded data.

Comment: The path is existing with my physical path in the console log like you saw. It's a HTML project working with AngularJS. I want to upload the image to my folder (ProjectRoot/img/) and after i will take the image path and save it to my json data. I watched a lot of videos,read a lot of solutions about uploading file with angularjs. I did the same thing all of my trials but every solution responded with this error.

the structure

Project
-img
-js
--angularjs and other scripts
--app.js
-index.html

Comment: I'm having trouble just with posting the file to folder.I can take the file from input and log it to console.